# Why my Android Layout Design is not working properly on my smartphone

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, user-interface

I have designed a Layout in Android Studio after crafting all the art in Adobe XD. The main problem is that It looks perfect in my Android Studio preview menu but as soon as I run my project on my Smartphone or even Virtual Device, the original design gets distorted or cannot be completely displayed on the screen. Why is this happening?

I have used everything as according to what documentations says. I mean, I have used 'sp' for text. Proper Margins and alignment etc.

**MY XML LAYOUT CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="365dp"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pics"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_height="152dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="34dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ebrima"
        android:text="Investigate comedy scenes for clues,
        bring the suspects in for questioning
        and analyze evidence to catch the
        killers. Are you ready to prove your
        detective skills?"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="162dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/stencil"
        android:text="CARTOON CRATE"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btnshape"
        android:text="Let's Go!"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.878"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.153" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/typo_round"
        android:text="Terms and Conditions"
        android:textColor="#EBC500"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.106" /></android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can see the

**What the Actual Design Appears in Android Studio Preview**

[image]

VS

**What the Layout Design Appears on my Smartphone device.**

[image]

Comment: Hello Haseeb, welcome to SO. A few comments about your Layout; you're hardcoding a lot of numbers and adding all these margins and sizes to widgets; at first sight this is not always a bad idea, but in this case, based off of the very little information visible, your real Smartphone's screen and density are not the same as the emulator/preview. This means the layout most likely does NOT fit in the space you're asking it to fit. Yes, you've used DP instead of PX (good!) but that doesn't mean that at *different* densities, the available space will be the same (nor the aspect ratio).

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of helping you grasp Constraint Layout better, I went ahead and did the same (similar) Layout in a much better, less hardcoded way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="225dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/title_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:text="cartoon crate"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header_image" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/body_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_text" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/terms_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Terms and Conditions"
            android:textColor="#FFC107"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/go_button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/body_text" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/go_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Let\'s go!"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/terms_button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/terms_button" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: How it looks]

Of course, this is just a sample, you'd need to account for a lot of other things. 
Notice how the only hardcoded values are truly the image height (not needed if I had your original image, you should use aspectRatio for that one), and then the padding/margins to make it look better. (These could be in the dimens.xml anyway).

Hope this gives you a better idea.

The Let's go and terms & conditions link are in a horizontal chain, but you can play with its placement; it's not clear from your sshot, if the button is supposed to be pinned at the right margin or where.

In the end, if there are enough pixels, things should fit it most devices.